# How to put a progress bar with thread safety in android while hitting a server and waiting for response?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, thread-safety, background-process

I have an application where I am recording audio in an activity. User has a start recording and stop recording button to do that. Once user clicks the stop recording button, it sends the recorded mp3 file to server (encoded string) and server process it and a response is received. I want to do the following tasks:

1. Since this process is long, I want to do this in a separate thread(preferably).
2. The process of sending and receiving response is to be shown using progress bar.
3. User should be able to navigate to other screens while he is waiting(i.e. current activity may be destroyed)

I tried using Toast messages before and after the function where I send mp3 to server. But there is no sync, sometimes msg comes early, sometime it's late. That's why a proper progress bar is required.How to do this? Can AsyncTask be used with what I want to achieve in (3). or should I use some other form of multithreading. Please help.Below is the activity

(Please ignore the indentations, I couldn't fix the code on stack-overflow:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static String msg = "default";

public final static String Result_MESSAGE = "in.innovatehub.ankita_mehta.tinyears.ResultMESSAGE";

private static final int REQUESTCODE_RECORDING = 109201;
private Button mRecorderApp = null;

private static String mFileName = "music.mp3";
private static String mFilePath =     String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/TinyEars/"));

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

private ImageButton mRecordImageButton = null;
private ImageButton mPlayImageButton = null;

boolean mStartRecording = true;
boolean mStartPlaying = true;

private Button mShowStatsButton = null;

private static final String TAG = "RecordActivity";

private Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
if(mRecorder!=null) {
int maxAmplitude = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();

if (maxAmplitude != 0) {
// visualizerView.addAmplitude(maxAmplitude);
}
}
else{

}
}
};

private void onRecord(boolean start) {
if (start) {
startRecording();
} else {
stopRecording();
}
}

private void onPlay(boolean start) {
if (start) {
startPlaying();
} else {
stopPlaying();
}
}

private void startPlaying() {
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
mPlayer.setDataSource(mFilePath+"/"+mFileName);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
Log.i("Completion Listener", "Song Complete");
stopPlaying();
mRecordImageButton.setEnabled(true);
}
});

} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}
}

private void stopPlaying() {
if (mPlayer != null) {
mPlayer.reset();
mPlayer.release();
mPlayer = null;
mPlayImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
//  mStartPlaying = true;
} else {
mPlayImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);
//   mStartPlaying = false;
}
}

private void startRecording() {
AudioRecordTest(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFilePath+"/"+mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
try {
mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}
try {
mRecorder.start();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start() failed");
}
}

private void stopRecording() {
if (mRecorder != null) {
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.release();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mRecorder = null;
mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.micicon);
// mStartRecording = true;
} else {
mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopicon);
// mStartRecording = false;
}
}

public void AudioRecordTest(String text) {
boolean exists = (new File(mFilePath+"/"+mFileName)).exists();
if (!exists) {
new File(mFileName).mkdirs();
}
//  mFileName += "audiorecordtest.mp3";
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

Log.d(TAG,"HERE IS FILE PATH"+mFilePath+"/"+mFileName);

mRecordImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
mPlayImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
mShowStatsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showMeStats);
mRecorderApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recorderApp);

AudioRecordTest("00000");

mRecordImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// Perform action on click
onRecord(mStartRecording);
if (mStartRecording) {
mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopicon);
mPlayImageButton.setEnabled(false);
//setText("Stop recording");
} else {
mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.micicon);
mPlayImageButton.setEnabled(true);
mShowStatsButton.setEnabled(true);
mShowStatsButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hold on... we are getting the results!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
pressedSavBtn();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Parsing done ... now you may see the results!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//setText("Start recording");
}
mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
}
});
mPlayImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// Perform action on click
onPlay(mStartPlaying);
if (mStartPlaying) {
mPlayImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);
mRecordImageButton.setEnabled(false);
mShowStatsButton.setEnabled(false);
//setText("Stop playing");
} else {
mPlayImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
mRecordImageButton.setEnabled(true);
mShowStatsButton.setEnabled(false);
//setText("Start playing");
}
mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
}
});
//Calling recorder ...
mRecorderApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
if (isAvailable(getApplicationContext(), intent)) {
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_RECORDING);
}
}
});
mShowStatsButton = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.showMeStats);
mShowStatsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
sendResults(msg);
}
});

}

public void pressedSavBtn(){
try {
thread.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
mShowStatsButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}

public void writeToFile(String data)
{
// Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
final File path = new File(mFilePath+"/");
// Make sure the path directory exists.
if(!path.exists())
{
// Make it, if it doesn't exit
path.mkdirs();
}
final File file = new File(path, "config.txt");
// Save your stream, don't forget to flush() it before closing it.
try
{
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
myOutWriter.append(data);

myOutWriter.close();

fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
try {
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append((line + "\n"));
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
try {
is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
return sb.toString();
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
try {

//THIS IS FILE ENCODING CODE
File file = new File(mFilePath+"/"+mFileName);
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
Log.d("~~~~~~~~ Encoded: ", encoded);
writeToFile(encoded);

//THIS IS URL CONN CODE
String link = "http://192.168.50.0:9000/divide_result";
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
try {
// Add your data
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", "StackOverFlow"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", encoded));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String sb = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
Log.d(TAG,"MESSAGE NOW"+sb);
Log.d(TAG, sb);
msg = sb.toString();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
});

public void sendResults(String res){
Log.d(TAG, "Inside on create, Navigating to Result Screen Activity!");
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultsScreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Result_MESSAGE, res);
startActivity(intent);
}

public static boolean isAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
return list.size() > 0;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_RECORDING) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
Uri audioUri = intent.getData();
// make use of this MediaStore uri
// e.g. store it somewhere
}
else {
// react meaningful to problems
}
}
else {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode,
resultCode, intent);
}
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if (mRecorder != null) {
mRecorder.release();
mRecorder = null;
}
if (mPlayer != null) {
mPlayer.release();
mPlayer = null;
}
thread.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
if(mRecorder!=null) {
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.reset();
mRecorder.release();
}
}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
handler.post(updater);
}
}
```

Also below is the layout-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_record"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="in.innovatehub.mobile.ankita_mehta.tinyears.RecordActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_record"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/micicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/playicon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showMeStats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="loadStats"
            android:text="@string/showMeStats" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/recorderApp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/UseRecorderApp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loadStatsLinearLayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loadingMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/loadingMessage"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/downloadProgress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use asynctask to upload file on to server and with that use timertask to display progressbar

Comment: @Pravin will async task work if i change activity?

Comment: yes it will be but go with rhari answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to upload your content to the server. By default, it runs on a seperate thread and is not activity bound. Then use a broadcast receiver to communicate the result back to any activity. You can find an example [here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android).

For the progress bar, you can create a notification and [show the progress bar there](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html), this will not block your application's UI.

Comment: I really like the idea of putting the progress bar as notification! Thanks :)

Comment: Accept it if it is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

For hitting the server at you should use AsyncTask or Runnable thread, without disturb the main tread

for custome progress dialog use the following code

xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/layCustomContentProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/layCustomProgressHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/layCustomProgressInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

and the method

```
public Dialog getCustomPogressDialog(Context context, String heading, String text) {

    // Declare the customer dialog
    Dialog dlgProgress = new Dialog(context);

    //  Set no title for the dialog
    dlgProgress.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Set the content view to the customer_alert layout
    dlgProgress.setContentView(R.layout.layout_custom_process_progress);

    // Cancel the dialog when touched outside.
    dlgProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    // Set the main heading
    TextView dlgHeading = (TextView) dlgProgress.findViewById(R.id.layCustomProgressHeading);
    dlgHeading.setText(heading);

    // set the info
    TextView dlgInfo = (TextView) dlgProgress.findViewById(R.id.layCustomProgressInfo);
    dlgInfo.setText(text);

    // Return the refenrece to the dialog
    return dlgProgress;

}
```